# How to use intent:// to open a PDF in Android Chrome and Angular (6)

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome, pdf, android-intent

I have a page that lists PDFs and everything works fine until you try and open one in Chrome on Android. I have searched and found references to using 'intent://' but have not been able to figure it out.

In my component I have the following intent path that I append to the URL

```
  intentPath = '#Intent;scheme=http;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end';
```

And the link itself is built in the component with:

```
  androidOpenPDF(url) {
    let newURL = url.replace('http', 'intent') + this.intentPath;
    window.open(newURL, "_blank");
  }
```

The HTMl is:

```
<a class="btn" target="_blank" (click)="androidOpenPDF(pdfURL)">VIEW PDF</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem the below code worked for me :

```
public void openPdf() {
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.someurl.com/some-pdf"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that's for when you're working with an App. My issue is specific to an angular site/html page.

Comment: Did you fixed that issue?